# Laravel log errors in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.1 application, I've set `APP_DEBUG` to false for my production environment. However, I'd still like to see errors (exceptions) being logged to the log file.

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` I see the following method:

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    return parent::report($e);
}
```

where the `parent::report` method uses `LoggerInterface` to log errors. So I expect this already being taken care of for me. Nevertheless I don't see exceptions in my logfile.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are log files empty? Also don't forget to check files under storage/logs directory, in my app, log files are in the form laravel-2015-11-30.log. Maybe you checked the wrong file? (I did it once.)

Comment: @berkayk Thanks, but I indeed checked the files under `storage/logs`. I use daily log files, but none exist in that folder.

Comment: Have you checked write permissions as well? I know these are really basic questions but sometimes you miss these details.

Comment: Did the check now, seems to be ok (`storage/logs` is writeable by `apache` user): `drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache   69 Nov 30 15:07 logs`

Comment: Try triggering an log message manually - `Log::info('Test log message.');
`. If that doesn't work you'll know there's something wrong "further down".
If you can, you can also try and enabling debug mode temporarily for the prod environment, say in the middle of the night - or some other time you web app/site has no users.

Comment: Or, maybe you have som kind of configuration that makes the log writer not writing logs to disk? Check out the `'log'` setting in `config/app.php`, if it's set to `syslog` or `errorlog` it will not create log files in storage/logs

Comment: For some reason, logging to file works again without touching anything. Might have been a server side issue. Thanks for the help everyone.